# How to remove Warnings when launching alloy, also my alloy GUI have some stripes that looks like an issue

Tags: alloy

**I am getting the following warning when I am launching alloy from my terminal**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4whole.SimpleGUI (file:/home/manish/alloy/alloy4.2_2015-02-22.jar) to field java.lang.ClassLoader.usr_paths

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4whole.SimpleGUI
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access     operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Loaded: libminisat.so
Loaded: libminisatprover.so
Loaded: liblingeling.so
Loaded: libglucose.so
Loaded: libcryptominisat.so
```

My System Configuration is following:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Graphics Card: GTX 1050
NVIDIA-SMI 440.64       Driver Version: 440.64       CUDA Version: 10.2

Java Version:
openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Also, my alloy is hanging my system, time and again. Thus, I am forced to restart alloy. I don't know if that has to do with this warning.**

**Alloy GUI visualization issue:**
[image: Alloy GUI have stripes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, running Java 8. Java is making significant changes that cause these warnings. Very annoying, breaking the long model of backward compatibility.

This is the reason that on MacOS we include the JVM. We could use someone that could do the same for Windows & Linux.

Comment: thanks, It worked. Now I am not getting any warnings. 

Also, do you have also have some idea about the stipes that I get in my GUI? If you will see my GUI screen then you will see some vertical lines.

Comment: The advantage of Java is supposed to be that it works anywhere :-( You might see if it works better with another VM? You can try AdoptJDK or Zulu.